# AWS ECS Cluster Service la tarea se detiene

Tags: web, docker, aws, cluster, amazon

he creado un cluster en aws con un service y una tarea con un contenedor de docker con load balancer, me levanta bien y puedo consumir la tarea creada, la cuestion es que despues de unos pocos minutos la tarea se apaga sola e inicie otra, este es el error que me aparece:

```
STOPPED (Task failed ELB health checks in (target-group arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:us-east-2:XXXXXXXXXXXX:targetgroup/fargate-tg/XXXXXXXXXXXX))
```

No se a que se deba este error, agradecería mucho su ayuda.

Comment: verifica el endpoint que utilices de healthcheck en tu app. Puede ser que te este devolviendo algo erroneo y el balanceador este cerrando la tarea y creando una nueva cada vez. Mira tambien en la opcion "stop" de las tareas, seguro que ves muchas...

Answer (score 0):

Esto es por que el load balancer esta mirando si la tarea sigue "viva" para eso lo que hace es hacer una petición get a ese servicio y ver que devuelve 200 si el servicio no responde o da error el load balancer piensa que el servidor esta "muerto" y cierra la tarea y genera una nueva.

Esto se hace para verificar que el servicio siempre este disponible.

Verifica la configuración y que tengas un endpoint para verificar el estado de tu servicio.